# Bootable USB with ISO undetected by Mac but detected by Linux

Tags: macos, boot, usb, iso-image

I have a custom ISO that I am trying to boot on a Macbook Pro using USB. I am following instructions from [here](http://business.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-drive-for-mac-in-os-x--cms-21253) and [here](https://thomashunter.name/blog/how-to-burn-an-iso-to-a-usb-drive-in-osx/). But when I start the laptop while pressing `Option` button, I only see the option of Internet recovery, whereas I should be seeing the option of "EFI Boot".

I know the problem is not with the USB or laptop because I tried to do the same with one of Linux distribution (14.04) ISO and it worked. I could see the option of "EFI boot" when starting up. With the custom ISO, I am able to make the USB bootable, but Mac's startup options is just not recognizing it (it works fine on Linux).

My question is, what could be the reason behind this? I have the shell script files that build the ISO I am talking about. What changes can I make in that to get rid of or isolate the problem?

Comment: Hold Opt at boot to see the list of bootable devices, not Cmd. "The laptop uses BIOS mode." is confusing... Macs don't have a BIOS.

Comment: @Tetsujin sorry, I was using `Option` button, made a mistake in typing. Corrected. For BIOS mode, this is what I consulted: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162564/how-can-i-tell-if-my-system-was-booted-as-efi-uefi-or-bios

Comment: Your link is for "PC"s. Macs just don't have a BIOS, never have. My instinct is 'it's a red herring' & will not be helping you in the slightest. It shouldn't even find  `/sys/firmware/efi` because Mac has no such directory, it doesn't even have `/sys` by default. I'm guessing you're going to need a Mac-specific guide, but I'm afraid I cannot help on that front, sorry.